# Byte vs bit @ linux TC

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am confused at the usage of 'Byte' and 'bit' when using `linux tc`

[**linux tc-tbf**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-tbf) said it use 'Byte'

> tbf - Token Bucket Filter
>
> Synopsis
>
> tc qdisc ... tbf rate rate burst bytes/cell ( latency ms | limit bytes ) [ mpu bytes [ peakrate rate mtu bytes/cell ]. 
>   burst is also known as buffer and maxburst. mtu is also known as minburst.

But I find it use 'bit'. it use a small letter 'b'

```
nimdrak@nimdrak-VirtualBox:~/custom/simple_experiment/link_capacity$ 
sudo tc -s -s -d c ls dev s2-eth3

class htb 1:1 root prio 0 quantum 200000 rate 200000Kbit ceil 200000Kbit 
linklayer ethernet burst 65000b/1 mpu 0b overhead 0b cburst 65000b/1 mpu 0b 
overhead 0b level 0 

 Sent 2265264968 bytes 37732 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 

 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 

 lended: 37732 borrowed: 0 giants: 0

 tokens: 3098 ctokens: 3098
```

I think linux tc use 'b, bit' as a standard unit because it shows 'b' at a terminal.

But I am not sure.

How can I be sure what is right between Byte and bit?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 'Byte' although it used a small 'b'

You can find this what `TC` use byte as a basic unit at a source code

The variable `buffer' is the burst value and printed by the debug command.

https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/tc/q_htb.c
https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/tc/tc_util.c

```
<tc/q_htb.c>
//buffer is from burst argument

...
if (!buffer)
    buffer = rate64 / get_hz() + mtu;
if (!cbuffer)
    cbuffer = ceil64 / get_hz() + mtu;


<tc_utils.c>

int get_rate64(__u64 *rate, const char *str)
{
    char *p;
    double bps = strtod(str, &p);
    const struct rate_suffix *s;
...

    bps /= 8; /* -> bytes per second */
    *rate = bps;
    return 0;
}

...
static int htb_print_opt(struct qdisc_util *qu, FILE *f, struct rtattr *opt)
{
    if (show_details) {
        fprintf(f, "burst %s/%u mpu %s ",
            sprint_size(buffer, b1),
            1<<hopt->rate.cell_log,
            sprint_size(hopt->rate.mpu, b2));
        fprintf(f, "cburst %s/%u mpu %s ",
            sprint_size(cbuffer, b1),
            1<<hopt->ceil.cell_log,
            sprint_size(hopt->ceil.mpu, b2));
        fprintf(f, "level %d ", (int)hopt->level);
...
}
...

static void print_size(char *buf, int len, __u32 sz)
{
    double tmp = sz;

    if (sz >= 1024*1024 && fabs(1024*1024*rint(tmp/(1024*1024)) - sz) < 1024)
        snprintf(buf, len, "%gMb", rint(tmp/(1024*1024)));
    else if (sz >= 1024 && fabs(1024*rint(tmp/1024) - sz) < 16)
        snprintf(buf, len, "%gKb", rint(tmp/1024));
    else
        snprintf(buf, len, "%ub", sz);
}

char *sprint_size(__u32 size, char *buf)
{
    print_size(buf, SPRINT_BSIZE-1, size);
    return buf;
}
```